# polylogarithmic space

Tags: time-complexity, alternation

I apologize if this is a silly question, but could someone tell me whether the class polyL (polylogarithmic space) is equal to the class ATIME(polylog)? If so, where can I find a reference to this or is it obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$SPACE[polylog(n)]=ATIME[polylog(n)]$ citing that $ATIME[s(n)]\subseteq SPACE[s(n)]\subseteq ATIME[(s(n))^2]$. This follows from a modified proof of Savitch's Theorem and is a pretty standard exercise in Complexity Theory courses. I'm not sure where this theorem first appeared, but I'll happily add a link to the paper if I find it or if someone links it in the comments.

Comment: And these inclusions hold for sublinear bounds as well?

Comment: It does require random access (so it will not hold for strict Turing machines).

Comment: It’s difficult to pinpoint a single original reference for these results, as they are in a sense older than the “random access” Turing machine model itself. Anyway, the following papers in between them should cover all the relevant material: Borodin, [On relating time and space to size and depth](https://doi.org/10.1137/0206054); Chandra, Kozen, Stockmayer, [Alternation](https://doi.org/10.1145/322234.322243); Ruzzo, [On uniform circuit complexity](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000(81)90038-6).